# Integrate two databases in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, table-relationships

We have 3 databases with same table but different data in them, on 3 servers, now we have a stronger server and we need to integrate 3 in 1. How can we have all data on one database? I have problem with relations of tables, if the primary key of a table change, what will happen with related table? How can I do this job without data loss?
I'm not a DBA but I'm comfortable working with queries and such in SSMS. I'm the only one who updates the data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the T-SQL Merge Function?

[MSDN T-SQL Merge Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

This can be used to Sync data between multiple tables.

Don't forget you can access multiple databases in a single query by specifying the full path of the table - [Server\Instance].[Database].[Schema].[Table].

You must also preserve referential integrity by updating the Parent tables (Primary keys) first and then the Child Tables (Foreign keys) thereafter.